# ReactJS - Custom hook to create a single object with the data collected from multiple form components

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I’ve been working for a couple of days on this little personal challenge (Just for learning purposes). Basically what I’d like to accomplish is the following:

- Create a custom hook that gathers data from multiple form components.
- Get the hook to return a new object with all the data gathered from
  the form components.
- Be able to use that returned object in any other component.

[image]

As you can see on this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/usegetformdata-76ti0?file=/src/App.js)  I’ve been able to get the hook to gather data from the FormComponents, however I’m not getting the desired results, since when I call the hook on the App component it’s not returning the correct data.

Additionally, when I display the `newObj` data to the screen it only shows the data from that specific FormComponent but not from the others.

The motivation for creating this hook is to find an alternate way to avoid state drilling in large scale projects. I know there’s a few methods to accomplish that. But I wanted to tackle the problem with a different approach by creating a custom hook.

The problem seems to be (judging by the console logs) that the hook is returning a ‘different’ object for every component from which it’s being called.

So far I’m not sure why it’s not working, or even if this is possible to accomplish in React.

Comment: The pattern you are describing is [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html). The `useCustomHook` is a Context provider, and the forms and display component are all Context consumers. Although they consume the context in different ways, some reading from it and some writing to it. It will achieve what you're after so long as all four consumers are children of the provider. Otherwise you'll need a management solution like Redux. A "custom hook" is just a piece of packaged React logic, there's nothing special about them per se.

Comment: I didn't consider using context. I'm going to implement it and see where it takes me. I know hooks aren't that great of a deal per se. I just wanted to get myself a fun little challenge with educational purposes. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to "share" data in your app.
First create context, provider and hook to access context data.

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";

const FormContext = React.createContext();

export const useFormData = () => useContext(FormContext);

export const FormDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    data1: "string",
    data2: "string",
    data3: "string",
    data4: "string",
    data5: "string",
    data6: "string"
  });
  const updateData = (newData) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, newData });
  };
  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{ formData, setFormData, updateData }}>
      {children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Than wrap your components with created provider component.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <FormDataProvider>
      <div
        className="App"
        style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-around" }}
      >
        <Form1 />
        <Form2 />
        <Form3 />
      </div>
    </FormDataProvider>
  );
}
```

Now you can access context data with created hook inside children like this

```
const { formData, setFormData } = useFormData()
```

Here is [modified code](https://codesandbox.io/s/usegetformdata-forked-fcp4r)

Comment: Hey man thank you for taking the time to modify the code. You’re completely right, using context did really hit the target. I’m going to keep experimenting with context and see what else I can do with it. Like I’ve said before, this was just a fun little personal challenge to help me learn more about custom hooks. Now I can start learning more about context as well thanks to you.